# Pedestrian/Object detection

Tags: object-detection, algorithm, autonomous-vehicles

Today automobiles have many kinds of detection systems and I'm currently researching one on Pedestrian Detection systems.
I haven't figured exactly out the difference between these three systems. If anyone experienced on this could give me explonation.

1. Monocular camera with RADAR
2. Stereo Camera with RADAR
3. Stereo Camera.

This far i know, that camera "sees" object, it does it's thing to know if its Human or Car ect.., then RADAR is used to calculate the distance (Dopplers effect).
But when we have Stereo Camera, is this used to also calculate the distance? As it can form 3D pictures?

Or what are the reasons to use Stereo Camera and RADAR together? On Monocular Camera it makes sense becuase it cant measure distance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please put your **specific question** in the title?